# I don't want to display a <div> in mobile views

Tags: javascript, php, width

I made a website with php, with some `<div>` tags in the php homepage file. That works well. But I don't want to display a `<div>` in mobile view. I am trying to learn some javascript features like `screen.width`, `screen.innerWidth`, etc. I tried using `screen.width` along with `if`...`else` statement in javascript, but still unsuccessful. What should be the code for:

To display a `<div id="got">Example</div>` in Desktops and laptops, but not in devices with width less than 500px. The homepage file is in php, so is it recommended to use javascript in it? or is php preferred?

Comment: 1) post you current code, 2) keep in mind that you can achieve this with css3 without using js (search for media queries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is not possible to detect the screen width easily with PHP.

But you can detect whether a mobile device or not easily.

**For that use the below code.**

```
<?php
$ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
if (
stristr($ua, "Windows CE") or
stristr($ua, "AvantGo") or
stristr($ua,"Mazingo") or
stristr($ua, "Mobile") or
stristr($ua, "T68") or
stristr($ua,"Syncalot") or
stristr($ua, "Blazer") ) {
  $DEVICE_TYPE="MOBILE";
}
if (!(isset($DEVICE_TYPE) and $DEVICE_TYPE=="MOBILE")) {

 //put  your div to be not shown on mobile devices here.

}
?>
```

**or with javascript code below.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
     document.getElementById('got').style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

**or with css code below**

```
<style type="text/css">
    @media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
        #got {
                 display: none;
                 }
    }
</style>
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score -1):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  #got {
      display：none；
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer to make it more useful for other OP and other readers.